# Auto Show Soft Keyboard on mobile web browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, keyboard

I want to make the soft keyboard show on

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
....
});
```

here's my html code:

```
<form id="typerForm">
<input id="typer" style="position:relative; left:-100em;"/>
</form>

<div id="myInput" style="border:2px solid #4AA; width:6em; height:1em; font-size:2em"></div>
<div style="height:20em; background-color:#eee">

</div>
```

and here's my javascript code:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('#typer').focus();
    $('#typer').select();

});


$('#typerForm').submit(function() {
    //alert("submit");
    setTimeout("$('#typer').focus();", 1000);
    return false;
});

$('#typer').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var input = $.trim($(this).val());
    // some lines of code..
    $('#myInput').text(input);
    //...
    //$(this).val('').focus(); // clean up
});
```

or you can look at my code here http://jsfiddle.net/7urry794/

my code works to show the keyboard on mobile web browser when i click on somewhere or click on the input text. And what i want is show keyboard automatically  when the page ready or finish loading

Comment: Please provide [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Else as soon as your link is broken, nobody will be able to re-use the help provided to solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

you can use below code to open keyboard on iOS or Android
There are a couple of ways I know of to get around this:

`prompt()` opens the keyboard

If you trigger the `.focus()` from within a `.click()` event (e.g. from opening your dialog), the keyboard shows up

Hope it might help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling `focus()` then `click()` on the input, but only if the script is initiated by user input. All attempts to get this to work from an onload handler with no user interaction **FAILED :-(** Beware of endless loops if your script is triggered by an onclick() on a containing element. The script below is working for me on Chrome for android 58 and Safari mobile 602.1, when called from an onclick().

```
function onSomethingOtherThanLoad(event){
    // get the input
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    if (event.target != target) {
        target.focus();
        target.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. it's just focus on the input text but doesn't show the keyboard  http://jsfiddle.net/o0zpj7r0/. I use chrome for android too

Comment: You need to put my script inside an event handler. What event do you want to trigger the soft keyboard?

Comment: all i want are, when i open the page and the page is finish on load/ ready i want to show the key board to input number in my input text then i click submit to post my input data. Could you suggest me what event i have to trigger the soft keyboard?

Comment: Ok this might be a hard limitation. It works if the script is called from an onclick handler, but the same script called from document.onload, or a timeout set by document.onload has no effect.

Comment: It looks like chrome is insisting that there be user input. If you put an alert() in the script, and the user has to click OK, then the soft keyboard pops.